# response does not return mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

It does not return anything back (hang state) and i see in console
`{ _id: 5f05d1527de7984a2c998385, name: 'alexa', age: 12 }`. I tried both method promise and callback but still same. Can you guess what could be the issue?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(express.json());

const TestModel = mongoose.model(
    'test',
    new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        age: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
        },
    }),
);

app.post('/test', async (req, res, next) => {
    const testUser = req.body;
    const Test = new TestModel(testUser);
    console.log(Test);
    /* Test.save(function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            return res.json({ message: 'something went wrong' });
        }
        res.json(testUser);
    }); */
    await Test.save();
    res.json(testUser);
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('playground is up');
});
```

Comment: Have you checked that the database connection is successfully established?

Comment: I dont see any connection snippet in your code, are you connecting to any database ?!

Comment: yes @thammada.ts i dont know whats wrong here with database i changed it to another database it is working as expected, Thank you i added callback in mongoose.connect
>Marc mongoose connect in another file sorry i forget to paste it